# Take one array and return 3 equal arrays if the array is not divisible by three, increase the size of the smaller array?

Tags: python

I have a challenge I cannot solve:

> Create​ ​a​ ​function​ ​that​ ​accepts​ ​a​ ​single​ ​array​ ​as​ ​an​ ​argument.​ ​Given​ ​an​ ​array​ ​of​ ​integers,​ ​x,​ ​sort x​ ​and​ ​split​ ​the​ ​integers​ ​into​ ​three​ ​smaller​ ​arrays​ ​of​ ​equal​ ​length.​ ​If​ ​the​ ​length​ ​of​ ​x​ ​is​ ​not​ ​evenly divisible​ ​by​ ​three,​ ​increase​ ​the​ ​size​ ​of​ ​the​ ​smaller​ ​arrays​ ​by​ ​one​ ​starting​ ​from​ ​the​ ​first​ ​array.​ ​The function​ ​should​ ​return​ ​an​ ​array​ ​of​ ​arrays. Example: # myArry ​= ​[2,1,3,4,7,5,9,6,8,13,12,11,10,0,15,16,14] # Output​ ​=​ ​[​ ​[0,​ ​1,​ ​2,​ ​3,​ ​4,​ ​5],​ ​[6,​ ​7,​ ​8,​ ​9,​ ​10,​ ​11],​ ​[12,​ ​13,​ ​14,​ ​15,​ ​16]​ ​] –

I have a solution, it just doesn't work if the array length is not at least 3. I also feel there is a shorter way of writing this.

```
a = [2,1,3,4,7,5,9,8,12,11,10,0,15,16,14]
b = [2,1,3,4,7,5,9,8,12,11,10,0,15,16]
c = [2,1,3,4,7,5,9,8,12,11,10,0,15]
d = [1]

def myfunc(ar):
    length = len(ar)
    s = sorted(ar)
    n3 = length//3 
    if(length % 3 == 0):
        return [s[index:index+n3] for index in range(0, length, n3)]
    else:
        num = (len(b) // 3 +1)
        A, B, C = [s[index:index+num] for index in range(0, length, num)]
        if(len(C) != len(A)): 
            C.append(C[-1]+1)
        return A,B,C
    return s

print(myfunc(a)) 
print(myfunc(b))
print(myfunc(c))[cannot split an array with a length less than 3 by n][1]
```

#### Example:

**Input**

```
myArry ​= ​[2,1,3,4,7,5,9,6,8,13,12,11,10,0,15,16,14]
```

**Output**

```
​[​ ​[0,​ ​1,​ ​2,​ ​3,​ ​4,​ ​5],​ ​[6,​ ​7,​ ​8,​ ​9,​ ​10,​ ​11],​ ​[12,​ ​13,​ ​14,​ ​15,​ ​16]​ ​]
```

Comment: Please, show us the desired result (output) for each input.

Comment: Example:  
# myArry ​= ​[2,1,3,4,7,5,9,6,8,13,12,11,10,0,15,16,14]
# Output​ ​=​ ​[​ ​[0,​ ​1,​ ​2,​ ​3,​ ​4,​ ​5],​ ​[6,​ ​7,​ ​8,​ ​9,​ ​10,​ ​11],​ ​[12,​ ​13,​ ​14,​ ​15,​ ​16]​ ​]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your help, I got a working solution!

```
import numpy as np

def myfunc(ar):
    splited = np.array_split(sorted(ar), 3)
    A,B,C = [x.tolist() for x in splited]
    if(len(C) != len(A)): 
        C.append(C[-1]+1)
        if(len(C) != len(B)):
            B.append(B[-1]+1)

    return A,B,C
```

Thanks to  @igorkf

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install the `numpy` library.

```
import numpy as np

myArry = [2,1,3,4,7,5,9,6,8,13,12,11,10,0,15,16,14]
splited = np.array_split(sorted(myArry), 3)
result = [x.tolist() for x in splited]
result
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! I didn't know about the numpy library! That helps shorten my code! However, this is only half of the challenge. The arrays have to be of equal length, and ​If​ ​the​ ​length​ ​of​ ​the array passed in is​ ​not​ ​evenly divisible​ ​by​ ​three,​ ​increase​ ​the​ ​size​ ​of​ ​the​ ​smaller​ ​arrays​ ​by​ ​one​ ​starting​ ​from​ ​the​ ​first​ ​array.

Comment: With your help, I got a working solution!

Thanks YOU